# Stop jQuery Mobile swipe event double bubbling

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, touch, jquery

I have jQuery Mobile on iPad Safari and for some reason touch swipe events are firing twice.

People have reported the same problem over the past year as recently as this week but I cannot find an explanation for how to fix the double event without modifying jQuery Mobile and I do not want to do that.  [Thread on jQuery forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/double-event-firing-on-swipeleft-and-swiperight-events)

The follwoing element bindings for the swipe handler all have the same incorrect double-event result where the alert is called twice for every one swipe.

**How should jQuery Mobile touch events be bound in order to avoid double bubbling?**

```
// Test 1: Binding directly to document with delegate()
$(document).delegate(document, 'swipeleft swiperight', function (event) {
    alert('You just ' + event.type + 'ed!');
});


// Test 2: Binding to document with on() handler recommended as of 1.7 with and without preventDefault
$(document).on('swipeleft',function(event, data){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('You just ' + event.type + 'ed!');
});


// Test 3: Binding to body with on() with and without event.stopPropagation 
$('body').on('swipeleft',function(event, data){
   event.stopPropagation();
   alert('You just ' + event.type + 'ed!');
});


// Test 4: Binding to div by class
$('.container').on('swipeleft',function(event, data){
   event.stopPropagation();
   alert('You just ' + event.type + 'ed!');
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) was the trick, which is different from stopPropagation().  Ensuring the [jQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method is called in document.ready seems to help.  I was able to use any element selector to bind the events including using the swipeup and swipe down from [here](http://developingwithstyle.blogspot.com/2010/11/jquery-mobile-swipe-up-down-left-right.html)

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(document).on('swipeleft swiperight swipedown swipeup',function(event, data){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        console.log('(document).Stop prop: You just ' + event.type + 'ed!');
    });
});
```

Comment: I placed it under `$(document).bind('pageinit')` and it doesn't work. I had to put `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` in each swipe event handler to make it work

Comment: That makes sense. Your swipe events are firing twice and need to be stopped with `stopImmediatePropagation()` just like the answer above. The `pageinit` event isn't double bubbling so it doesn't require manual stopping. `pageinit` should only fire once per page but it fires again for each dynamically added page.

Comment: This does seem to have worked better than other solutions, though I'm still getting some screwy behavior on swiperight...my Android 4.x goes a little nuts with several (random?) pages before it lands on the right one.

Comment: Glad it was a step in the right direction. The strange behavior doesn't sound like a swipe event firing twice. Without seeing anything my first thought is jQuery struggles to compute the dimensions of all pages in the sequence the moment before the swipe animation happens. Even though it's at odds with responsive design, I've had better animation results by adding a fixed height and width to block elements like images. I think it helps with the animation math.

Answer (score 3):

Well, had the same problem with swipe event been called twice.
The workaround is to bind the event this way:

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', '#div_id',  function(event){
    //console.log("swipleft"+event);
    // code 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  I wonder if failing to pass the container as a parameter calls `on` once on any container that gets swiped and then immediately again on the document.

Comment: hum might be the problem...don't know exacly what happens. But there's a problem when attaching swipe on levels below Document.

Comment: This one helped me. I actually just tested with binding to document with swipeleft and not also swiperight, and this led both events to fire twice. The moment I also changed it for swiperight both events fired once, as expected. (And there was no need for event.stopImmediatePropagation()).

Answer (score 0):

it really helped in my case too. I was trying to swipe pages with mobile jquery and swipe events( left and right ) were triggering several times. **event.stopImmediatePropagation()** it worked like a charm. Thank you !!

here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).bind( 'pageinit', function(event) { 
        $("div:jqmData(role='page')").live('swipeleft swiperight',function(event){
            if (event.type == 'swipeleft') { 
                var prev = $(this).prev("div:jqmData(role='page')");
                if(typeof(prev.data('url')) !='undefined') {
                    $.mobile.changePage(prev.data('url'), { transition: 'slide', reverse: false});
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }
            }
            if (event.type == 'swiperight') { 
                var next = $(this).next("div:jqmData(role='page')"); 
                if(typeof(next.data('url')) != 'undefined') {
                    $.mobile.changePage(next.data('url'), { transition: 'slide', reverse: false});
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }                   
            }           
        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

HTML -

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-url="#page1"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div>
        <h1> Page 1 </h1>
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p>View internal page called</p>    
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                <li>Swipe Right to view Page 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-url="#page2"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div>
        <h1> Page 2 </h1>
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p>View internal page called</p>    
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                <li>Swipe Right to view Page 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```