# Apply stopImmediatePropagation() to all jQuery mobile events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to completely apply `stopImmediatePropagation()` across the board? Since I thought it was annoying to do that in each `tap` event handler, let say.

I commented in this question as an FYI:

[Stop jQuery Mobile swipe event double bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763983/stop-jquery-mobile-swipe-event-double-bubbling/9764254#comment30278353_9764254)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution is to do `event.stopImmediatePropogation();` on each handler function. It's a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropogation();
});
```

Comment: I tried with tap and it didn't work. Still trigger multiple times.